# How to optimize my parallax map disparity map?

Tags: depth, stereo-3d, 3d-reconstruction

I got the disparity map as follows using SGBM with wls.But there are some flaws in the disparity map obtained so that my pointcloud is poor either.Can someone tell me how to optimize it?

```
int dis2pcloud(Mat color,Mat depth)
{
    if (color.empty() || depth.empty())
    {
    cout << "The image is empty, please check it!" << endl;
    return -1;
    }
    PointCloud<PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud(new PointCloud<PointXYZRGB>);

    for (int row = 0; row < depth.rows; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < depth.cols; col++)
        {
            ushort d = depth.ptr<ushort>(row)[col];

            if (d==0)
                continue;
            PointXYZRGB p;

            p.z = fx * baseline / (d + doffs); // Zc = baseline * f / (d + doffs)

            p.x = (col - u0) * p.z / fx; 
            p.y = (row - v0) * p.z / fy;
            p.y = -p.y;  
            p.z = -p.z;
            p.b = color.ptr<uchar>(row)[col * 3];
            p.g = color.ptr<uchar>(row)[col * 3 + 1];
            p.r = color.ptr<uchar>(row)[col * 3 + 2];
            cloud->points.push_back(p);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[here is my disparity map,we can see that there is a clear gap in the lower left part of the pillow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cq7X.png)

[here is my pointcloud](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMUfr.png)

Comment: what can i do to the disparity map to optimize the situation